# Django remove Duplicates after filtering from model objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a model called **Course** , I have been trying to get a list of them using the filter function. Now each course has different fields.

My course model is:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    course_university = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course_instructor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course_year = models.IntegerField(('year'), validators=[MinValueValidator(1984), MaxValueValidator(max_value_current_year())])
    course_likes = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='course_likes')
    course_dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='course_dislikes')
    course_reviews = models.ManyToManyField(Review, blank=True, related_name='course_reviews')
```

I am trying to get the courses for instructor named "Smiths" at Oxford university

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(course_instructor="smiths",course_university="university")
```

How can I remove duplicated with this name for instance show the one with the latest year?
Sine, for example, there will be course **ABC123** by professor **Smith** in **Oxford** university in **years 2017,2018,2019,...** how can I return only one of those? I have tried `distinct()` but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do that? Or should I change the whole structure of my database?

**EDIT:** I tried this but it is still giving me duplicates:

```
course_dup = Course.objects.filter(course_instructor=par2,course_university=par1).values('course_instructor', 'course_university').annotate(course_year=Max('course_year'))
courses = Course.objects.filter(course_instructor__in=[c['course_instructor'] for c in course_dup], course_university__in=[c['course_university'] for c in course_dup])
```

So for clarification imagine there is the following values:

```
   course_code | course_instructor | course_year | course_university 

1. ABC123      | smith             | 2017        | Oxford
2. ABC123      | smith             | 2017        | Oxford
3. CDE123      | smith             | 2018        | Oxford
4. ADF123      | smith             | 2019        | Oxford
5. ABC123      | smith             | 2019        | Oxford
```

I want to return only for example **3,4,5** since **5** is the latest with course code **ABC123**, or even a query that returns **1,3,4** should work since 1 is the first hit matching the query. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your problem

```
course_dup = Course.objects.filter(course_instructor="smiths",course_university="university").values('course_instructor', 'course_university').annotate(course_year=MAX('course_year'))
```

Edit::
Since you want a query set then after this query you can run this

```
courses = Course.objects.annotate(combined_key=Concat('course_instructor', V('_'), 'course_university', V('_'), 'course_year',output_field=CharField())).filter(combined_key__in=["{}_{}_{}}".format(c['course_instructor'], c['course_university'], c['course_year']) for c in course_dup])
```

Comment: It seems that when I use this all of my methods for the course model won't work since this will return a dictionary. How can I return course objects? I want to return course objects with the query

Comment: `
courses = Course.objects.filter(course_instructor__in=[c['course_instructor'] for c in course_dup], course_university__in=[c['course_university'] for c in course_dup])
`
This query is wrong

Answer (score -1):

This exclude the first value and delete the rest

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(course_instructor="smiths",course_university="university")
if len(courses) > 1:
    courses[1:].delete()
```